# Is it possible to use hooks on a single property of a context?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

I am trying to listen for changes on a single property of a context value. If I'm using a React context that has a value of an object with a dozen or so properties:

```
{
  prop1: "value1",
  prop2: "value2",
  prop3: "value3",
  ...
  prop12: "value12"
}
```

every component that has `useContext(MyContext)` will re-render.

```
function MyComponent() {
   const c = useContext(MyContext); // The full object

   const {prop1} = c; // This component only cares about prop1

   return <div>{prop1}</div>;
}
```

Since this component only cares about one property in the context, I don't want it to re-render if `prop1` remains the same. I'm trying to create a hook that would re-render based on a selector like this:

```
useContextProp(MyContext, c => c.prop1); // only re-renders when prop1 changes
```

but I can't find a way to subscribe to changes. Anyone know a trick?

---

**Update:**

My current solution is `useMemo` in the component to avoid re-rendering complex layouts:

```
function MyComponent() {
  const {prop1} = useContext(MyContext);

  // ... other possibly complex calculations

  return useMemo(() => <div>{prop1}</div>, [prop1]); // Assume complex layout
}
```

But this doesn't help me with the other parts of the component where there could be complex calculations, assembling data, etc. The particulars are not important, but it would be great if there was a hook that listened for one value so that I don't have to write `useMemo` everywhere.

Comment: Your component will re-render regardless but you can reduce the impact with memoization so the work to generate a component is re-used.

Comment: @SILENT, I added an update to answer you.

Comment: Maybe you should look on the implementation of react-redux useSelector

Comment: Maybe pass the prop from a parent Component and memoize MyComponent? All calculations and etc will only run if the memoized value changes.

Answer (score 0):

You can use React.memo to wrap your component and pass in the second argument a function that compare prev props to next props.

```
function MyComponent(props) {
  /* render using props */
}
function areEqual(prevProps, nextProps) {
  /*
  return true if passing nextProps to render would return
  the same result as passing prevProps to render,
  otherwise return false
  */
}
export default React.memo(MyComponent, areEqual);
```

See here in the docs https://reactjs.org/docs/react-api.html#reactmemo

If you use React-Redux their hooks are already optimised for that.

Answer (score 0):

Use useCallback hook to get a memoized callback.
https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#usecallback

```
const memoizedCallback = useCallback(
  () => {
    doSomething(a, b);
  },
  [a, b],
);
```